# Deflate in Perl fails in PHP

Tags: php, perl

I'm doing a Perl script to perform a deflate in Perl so I can test in PHP, the perl result works fine but when I try
In PHP the resulting code I receive the error "Warning: gzinflate(): data error in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3"

Source

```
use MIME::Base64;
use Compress::Zlib;

my $php_code  = "<?php echo 'hi world'; ?>"; #FAIL
#my $php_code = "echo 'hi world';"; FAIL

print "Original : ".$php_code."\n\n";

my $buffer;
my $d = deflateInit();

$buffer  = $d->deflate($php_code);
$buffer .= $d->flush();

print "After Encoded Base64 : ".$buffer."\n\n"; #

my $encoded = encode_base64($buffer,"");

print "Encoded : ".$encoded."\n\n";

$encoded = decode_base64($encoded);

#

print "After Decoded Base64 : ".$encoded."\n\n"; #

my $decoded;
my $i = inflateInit();

while ($encoded) {
    $decoded .= $i->inflate($encoded);
}

print "Decoded : ".$decoded."\n\n";
```

Output

```
Original : <?php echo 'hi world'; ?>

After Encoded Base64 : x£│▒/╚(PHM╬╚WP¤╚T(¤/╩IQÀV░À♥ jñÔ

Encoded : eJyzsS/IKFBITc7IV1DPyFQozy/KSVG3VrC3AwBqpAfi

After Decoded Base64 : x£│▒/╚(PHM╬╚WP¤╚T(¤/╩IQÀV░À♥ jñÔ

Decoded : <?php echo 'hi world'; ?>
```

PHP Source

```
<?php

$uncompressed = gzinflate(base64_decode("eJyzsS/IKFBITc7IV1DPyFQozy/KSVG3VrC3AwBqpAfi"));
eval($uncompressed);

?>
```

Output

```
Warning: gzinflate(): data error in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3
```

I try removing  Tags but the same error continues

How do I fix this error?

Comment: This works: `print htmlentities(gzinflate(base64_decode(base64_encode(gzdeflate("<?php echo 'hello world';?>")))));` error mst be somewhere else.

Comment: If you can read it http://perlenespanol.com/foro/post40077.html

Comment: Found this: http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/read-string-perl-compressed-php-gzdeflate-284237.html  but yo need the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the manual for the [`Compress::Zlib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::Zlib) module you'll find that you're using it wrongly. The result of the *deflate* operation is the output from `flush`, and you shouldn't be appending it to the output from `deflate`

The result of this program works fine in PHP, but note that you can't `eval "<?php echo 'hi world'; ?>"` because it doesn't expect `<?php ... ?>` around the code

#### Perl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use MIME::Base64;
use Compress::Zlib;

my $php_code  = "<?php echo 'hi world'; ?>";

print "Original: $php_code\n\n";

my $d = deflateInit;
$d->deflate($php_code);

my $buffer = $d->flush;

my $encoded = encode_base64($buffer, "");

print "After Encoded Base64: $encoded\n\n";
```

#### output

```
Original: <?php echo 'hi world'; ?>

After Encoded Base64: s7EvyChQSE3OyFdQz8hUKM8vyklRt1awtwMAaqQH4g==
```

#### PHP

```php
<?php

$encoded = "s7EvyChQSE3OyFdQz8hUKM8vyklRt1awtwMAaqQH4g==";

$decoded = gzinflate(base64_decode($encoded));

echo '$decoded: ', $decoded, "\n";

?>
```

#### output

```
$decoded: <?php echo 'hi world'; ?>
```

Comment: Nice , thanks for the help , you are a hero Borodin xD.

Answer (score 0):

You **MUST** keep the data returned from both the `deflate` and `flush` methods.

In this particular instance ignoring the data returned from `deflate` just happens to work because the input is tiny. If you drop a bigger buffer into `deflate`, and ignore what it returns, you will end up with a corrupt data stream.

Here is a bit of background -- by default [Compress::Zlib](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.074/lib/Compress/Zlib.pm) will create an [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950) compliant compressed data stream. Looking at the definition of `gzinflate` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php), it appears that this method is expecting an [RFC 1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951) compliant data stream.

The reason the test code *happened* to work when the data returned from `flush` was ignored is down to the fact that an [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950) data stream is just an [RFC 1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951) data stream with a two byte header and four byte trailer.

The first call to `deflate` below will only return the two byte header because  `$php_code` only contains a few bytes of data

```
$buffer  = $d->deflate($php_code);
```

That means by ignoring the data returned from `deflate`, you end up with an [RFC 1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951) data stream with the trailer from [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950). The php `gzinflate` method seems to cope with that.

If the input data was longer it will return the two byte header *and* some compressed data.

To get [Compress::Zlib](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.074/lib/Compress/Zlib.pm) to create the correct data stream use this

```
my $d = deflateInit(-WindowBits => MAX_WBITS) ;
$buffer  = $d->deflate($php_code);
$buffer .= $d->flush();
```